# Display field for User ForeignKey in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
class Lab(Model):
  responsible = ForeignKey(User)
```

This is a very simplified version of my Django model. Basically the problem is in the Django admin, when I want to edit or add a new `Lab` object, the drop-down list containing the `User` objects only displays the `User.username` value, which are only numbers in my case.

I want the drop-down list to display `User.last_name` value.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why didn't you use a `OnetoOneField` on `User` objects?

Comment: Because several labs can have the same responsible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define your own user choice field for lab admin.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin


class UserChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.last_name

# Now you have to hook this field up to lab admin.

class LabAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'responsible':
            kwargs['form_class'] = UserChoiceField
        return super(LabAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Something like that. I didn't tested it so there may be some typos. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Default `User` model in django returns `username` as the object representation. If you want to change this, then you have to overwrite `__unicode__` method.

You cant write a [`proxy model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and then overwrite the `__unicode__` method to return `last_name`

Something like this:

```
class MyUser(User):
   class Meta:
      proxy = True

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name


class Lab(Model):
   responsible = ForeignKey(MyUser)
```